# Edit Garmin .img File

Tags: garmin

We use Garmin 60CSx hand units loaded with a custom .img file for our project site created years ago. I need to add some POI and trail data (currently in GPX format) to the .img file, and create an updated .img file.

I did most of what I need in mapwel, but then ran into the license issue (can't create .img without a license, and I don't have a garmin unit hady I can link a license to).

I was hoping a there might be a QGIS based (or other free) solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [mkgmap](http://www.mkgmap.org.uk/) to make IMG files for my Edge 810, but mkgmap needs to start with OpenStreetMap OSM files rather than GPX, so you would have to convert and edit your GPX data to OSM using something like [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) or [GPSBabel](https://www.gpsbabel.org/).

(GPSBabel, mkgmap and JOSM are all free.)

There is also something called [gpx2img](https://www.gpx2img.com/) but I've never used it.